# Invalid training data. For a recurrent layer with output mode 'last', responses must be a categorical column vector

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, lstm

(I'm new to Matlab and am trying to build an LSTM)
I've converted the Y into a categorical array:
    `labels = categorical(labels)
 net = trainNetwork(data, labels, layers, options);`

```
labels =   3×1 categorical array
1 
0 
0
```

However still get the error Invalid training data. For a recurrent layer with output mode 'last', responses must be a categorical column vector.

Answer (score 0):

the error here could be a little misleading. i can only guess but from a similar problem i had, i think you are not using cell array as input data. just convert your data to cell array and it should work fine.
for example if it's a 2 dimensional array, you could use :

```
data = num2cell(data,2);
```